# What's a good library for parsing mathematical expressions in java?

Tags: java, android, math, parsing

I'm an Android Developer and as part of my next app I will need to evaluate a large variety of user created mathematical expressions and equations.  I am looking for a good java library that is lightweight and can evaluate mathematical expressions using user defined variables and constants, trig and exponential functions, etc.

I've looked around and [Jep](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/) seems to be popular, but I would like to hear more suggestions, especially from people who have used these libraries before.

Answer (score 4):

[JEval](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/) is a good alternative. I abandoned Jep due to it becoming commercial. The only concern is that JEval seems to be a little dormant at the moment (last release in 2008).

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a simple but capable [Math Expression Evaluator](http://tech.dolhub.com/Code/MathEval) a while back, which is free and open-source.  It's main advantage is being fast and tiny - both are a good thing with hand-held devices.  If it meets your need you are welcome to use it.

#### Primary Features:

- Basic math operators, with inferred precedence (^ * × · / ÷ % + -).
- Explicit precedence with parenthesis.
- Implicit multiplication of bracketed subexpressions.
- Correct right-associativity of exponentials (power operator).
- Direct support for hexadecimal numbers prefixed by 0x.
- Constants and variables.
- Extensible operators.
- Extensible functions.
- 20 KiB footprint.

#### Example

```
MathEval math=new MathEval();

math.setVariable("Top",    5);
math.setVariable("Left",  20);
math.setVariable("Bottom",15);
math.setVariable("Right", 60);

System.out.println("Middle: "+math.evaluate("floor((Right+1-Left)/2)"));
```

Comment: Nice an small, but I'm afraid I need support for more advanced functions and expressions.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work great. Nice and simple.  Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer unless the code is posted here.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://code.google.com/p/expressionoasis/. It is an extensible Expression Evaluation framework and will meet such requirements.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by listing some of the features of this library or, perhaps, by explaining how it compares to other existing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly fit my initial conditions, but I found a wonderful parser written in C++.  I'm trying to figure out Android's Native code support to see if I can use it.  It's exactly what I need.

Here's the documentation for the project.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/MathieuMathParser.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a new commercial tool called [formula4j](http://www.formula4j.com/), which may be of interest to some.