# Regular Expressions in Java - Calculating value to Integer form

Tags: java, regex

I have a string something like :
String str="(2+(3*4))+(1+2)";
Somehow I want calculate its value in Integer format.
i.e. I should be able to get 2+12+3=17.
What matters for me is the End Result.

I used : str.replaceAll("\((.*?)\)", "$1"), which doesn't work properly and even I am not able to get the answer as Integer.

Can anyone Help me?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: regex is not for calculation, it's for pattern matching.

Comment: [In computing, a **regular expression** (abbreviated **regex** or **regexp**) is a sequence of characters that forms a search pattern, mainly for use in pattern matching with strings, or string matching, i.e. "find and replace"-like operations.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using regular expressions to perform mathematical tasks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form)

Answer (score 4):

[Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is good for that. Here's a [java applet with sourcecode](http://www.chris-j.co.uk/parsing.php) using this algorithm.

For expression evaluations, you can see these libraries-

> [Janino](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home) - This one is really amazing!
>
> [Jep Java](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/)
>
> [Mvel](http://mvel.codehaus.org/)

Using builtin [Javascript engine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/):

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class ExpressionEvaluation {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        final ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        final ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

        String expr = "(2+(3*4))+(1+2)";

        try {
            System.out.println(engine.eval(expr)); // prints out 17
        } catch(Exception ex){
            //TODO:  handle the exception
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, there's a few nice suggestions there - thank you for this answer, Sajal.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use the ScripEngine class in Java and invoke the eval() function to evaluate the expression.

I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form) can help you.

++

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Jeval](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/)

[And this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226863/whats-a-good-library-for-parsing-mathematical-expressions-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not a good idea for that.
You should parse the string and use a stack.

See here for the explanation of the algorithm (the third one):
http://www.smccd.net/accounts/hasson/C++2Notes/ArithmeticParsing.html