# Algorithm or Function to return Y values for X and Equation Inputs

Tags: java, android, function, equation, graphing

I am creating a graphing calculator and I need an algorithm to interpret equations that users input. For example, if the user types in "x^3+5x^2-4x-9", the algorithm should take the string input and return (0, -9), (1, -7) and so on. How should I go about doing this? Are there any open source libraries I can use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226863/whats-a-good-library-for-parsing-mathematical-expressions-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a `Shunting-Yard Algorithm`, but there are plenty of `mathematical parsers` already out there. There is a very famous saying in software development:

> "Don't reinvent the wheel."

I encountered this problem when developing my own app. If there's already open source libraries out there, you should definitely use them to your advantage. That being said, I would recommend the `MathEval` library if you want *double precision*. `Double` is usually enough in terms of `precision`, because `precision` after `double` such as `BigDecimal`, which is an exact way of representing numbers is **extremely expensive** in terms of `speed` and `memory`, two things you want to reduce in computation.

The easiest, `O(n)` method in which you would generate solutions is **set a range in a for loop**, and use `MathEval's setVariable` method for `x` based on the iterations in the loop and retrieve the result through `MathEval's evaluate` method. There could be some boundaries in the equation, so make sure you compute the necessary restrictions and condition them inside your loop.

Check out this link Terrance which mentions the `MathEval` library:
[Built-in method for evaluating math expressions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258538/free-java-library-for-evaluating-math-expressions/12304313?noredirect=1#comment51165418_12304313)

Let me know if you need any help because I have implemented both the `algorithm` from scratch and through an `external library`.